# Print ready billboard design example

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, raster

I made one simple example of print ready billboard design (4m x 3m) and I have some questions about it.

1.) In this example I used .jpg picture 7644x5000 and 96 dpi. I learned that for billboard in real size, raster image need to have at least 30 dpi. So if i resize this picture to 323cm x 211cm (and put it in the middle of billboard), it will have 60 ppi, which is enough for print. Am I right?

2.) Can I combine raster image and vector text in same design using Illustrator. I suppose yes.

3.) For large text I can use rich black and for small text k 100% black?

4.) When I design billboard I don't need bleed?

5.) I saw that many people suggest using of inDesign when combining vector and raster, but why i can't do it in Illustrator as well?

6.) When i convert text to outlines, I don't need to send font with pdf file?

7.) What preset should I use when saving pdf file?

I opened new document with 40cm x 30cm, 300 dpi, CMYK. Put the picture inside and some text with rich black. If I save it as .pdf and send it to print, what quality is it going to be? This is just an example and I'm not going to print this. :) Thank you.

[image: billboard example]

Answer (score 1):

Most of these are questions you need to ask the printer of the billboard. As for the questions we can answer:

> I saw that many people suggest using of inDesign when combining vector and raster, but why i can't do it in Illustrator as well?

You can if you want to. Personal preference. (Unless, again, the printer has a preference)

> When i convert text to outlines, I don't need to send font with pdf file?

Correct. That's the reason to convert to outlines in the first place (in most cases).

Comment: Suggest if you are spending bucks on the image stock, print and placement of your promotional efforts you could throw a few extra dollars at it and get a designer in, that's what we are here for.

Comment: But can you tell me if image of this quality can be used in billboard design. Or any large size banner.

Comment: @Pawlock you need to ask the printer. It's going to depend on a whole bunch of things...type of printing, distance a person is from the billboard, personal opinion, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I used .jpg picture 7644x5000 and 96 dpi.

That size is a very good one.

> I learned that for billboard in real size, raster image need to have at least 30 dpi.

Could be a lot less if needed.

> So if i resize this picture to 323cm x 211cm (and put it in the middle of billboard), it will have 60 ppi, which is enough for print. Am I right?

Yes that is correct.

> Can I combine raster image and vector text in same design using Illustrator.

In my opinion that is the way it should be always done.

> For large text I can use rich black and for small text k 100% black?

For large text in a banner you can use C100M100Y100K100. For small one... at that size there is no small text. But I would do all my texts the same rich black.

You could use also a cmyk black used by your color profile, lie c75m68y67k90.

> When I design billboard I don't need bleed?

Make a small bleed. 1-5cm becouse sometimes the canvas can be folded and ironed to have better streinght.

> I saw that many people suggest using of inDesign when combining vector and raster.

You can use either one.

> When I convert text to outlines, I don't need to send font with pdf file?

No. the text is text no more. Its just a shape.

> What preset should I use when saving pdf file?

Try using a PDFX family The X-3 allow you to icorporate the color profile, so that is a good option.

I opened new document with 40cm x 30cm, 300 dpi, CMYK. Put the picture inside and some text with rich black. If I save it as .pdf and send it to print, what quality is it going to be?

Make round numbers. As you have a very good size image, do a 1/5 scale file at 300 ppi.

(323/5) x (211/5) = 64.6x42.2 at 300ppi

When you send it to print tel them it is at that scale and your final output will be a 60ppi at full size.

Comment: Full on 100,100,100,100 % color may be too much ask the printer.

Comment: On a banner it is a common practice, but I edited that part with a 300% ink option.

Comment: sure but manufacturing techniques differ.